# Refining a query by Edge metadata

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases

I currently have two Vertex classes, `VersionSet` and `Version`, with one non-lightweight Edge class, `VersionSetToVersion`. The VersionSetToVersion edge class also has a property called `status` which can have the value 'latest'.

If I have some @rid of a VersionSet vertex (i.e. `#14:1`), how would I construct an orient-db style SQL query to retrieve only the Version vertex that has a VersionSetToVersion EDGE with a status of 'latest'?

Here's a query that will return all Versions related to the VersionSet with @rid #14:1 regardless of the status property

```
SELECT out('VersionSetToVersion') FROM #14:1
```

This returns two VersionSet objects: #15:1, and #15:2, but only the edge to #15:2 has the status of 'latest'.

How can I refine this query by the status property on the EDGE so only #15:2 is returned in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT outE('VersionSetToVersion')[status = 'latest'].inV() FROM #14:1
```

Answer (score 0):

`select out_VersionSetToVersion[status = 'latest'] from 14:1`